# sed: -e expression #1, char 93: unterminated `s' command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, sh

I am using the below script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "============================"

#Convert jpeg file to base64 format
var=`base64 HTMLImage1.jpg`
echo $var
sed -i 's|HTMLImage3.png|'"${var}"'|' Test.html

echo "============================"
```

to convert the jpg file in base64 file format and then replace the first occurence of the string "HTMLImage3.png" with the base64 encoded string. I am getting the base64 encoded on my console, so there is no issue in that. But while replacing the string "HTMLImage3.png" with the base64 encoded string, I am getting the below issue:

sed: -e expression #1, char 93: unterminated `s' command

Below is the sample base64 encoded string:

```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.....
```

My base64 encoded string contains "/" character as well. Is there anything incorrect in sed command present in shell script?

Comment: If I pipe the base64 output directly to sed command instead of saving it in a variable. Then how will I specify the base64 encoded string with which I have to replace the string. I have tried executing: base64 HTMLImage1.jpg|sed -i 's|HTMLImage3\.png|'"${var}"'|' Test.html but it is not helping as there is no value in var variable now. So in my output HTMLImage3.png is getting replaced with empty string.

Comment: I do not have to replace the entire line containing "HTMLImage3.png" string instead I just have to replace the text "HTMLImage3.png" with the base64 encoded string.

Comment: My first suggestion was to change how the output was stored.. ``var=`base64 HTMLImage1.jpg | sed '$!s/$/\\/'` ``

Comment: #!/bin/bash
echo "============================"

#Convert jpeg file to base64 format
var=`base64 HTMLImage1.jpg | sed '$!s/$/\\/'`
echo $var
sed -i 's|HTMLImage3\.png|'"${var}"'|' Test.html

#base64 HTMLImage1.jpg|sed -i 's|HTMLImage3\.png|'"${var}"'|' Test.html
echo "============================". Using your suggestion, now I am getting the below error: sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command.

Comment: not sure what else can go wrong.. can you try this: ``var=`base64 HTMLImage1.jpg` `` followed by `awk -v s="$var" '{sub(/HTMLImage3\.png/, s)} 1'`... if `base64` output can contain `&` character, then you need to escape it, so use `s="$(echo "$var" | sed 's/&/\\\\&/')"` instead of `s="$var"` in the above awk command

Comment: @DeepakJain: Since the message says that `sed` is missing a terminator (in your case '|'), the only way this error could occur would be if the last character of the base64-encoded string is a backslash character (`\`), which would escape the final `|`. Can you reproduce the error with a simpler input file, so that we can try it it with your input data?

Comment: I think `sed` doesn't like the line breaks in the command. The terminating pipe character should be in the same line as the start of the `s` command.

Comment: Consider just adding the -w0 option to base64 as potong suggests.  This will avoid the new lines that will cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and bash):

```
sed -E 's#(.*)HTMLImage3.png(.*)#echo "\1$(base64 -w0 HTMLImage1.jpg)\2"#e' file
```

Replace the required string by the output of the required file passed to base64.

N.B. The entire line must be represented in the RHS of the substitution command, thus the contents left and right of the  match must be captured and redisplayed in the `echo` command. The `-w0` option to base64, removes any line feeds used to wrap the output.